# Why $f_y(x+\delta x,y)=f_y(x,y)+o(1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am currently doing some independent study and came across a set of notes, within these notes a proof of the multivariable chain rule is given.

The proof it gives is:

> Consider an arbitrary displacement in any direction $(x, y)→(x+δx, y+δy)$.  We have
>   $$ \begin{align*} δf &= f(x + δx, y + δy) − f(x, y) \\
>  &= f(x + δx, y + δy) − f(x + δx, y) + f(x + δx, y) −f(x, y) \\
>  &= f_y(x + δx, y)δy + o(δy) + f_x(x, y)δx + o(δx) \\
>  &= (f_x(x, y) + o(1))δy + o(δy) + f_x(x, y)δx + o(δx) \\
> δf &= \frac{δf}{δx} δx + \frac{δf}{δy} δy + o(δx,δy) \end{align*} $$

It appears we are to understand that $f_y(x+\delta x,y)=f_y(x,y)+o(1)$ where $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, in passing from the third line of the chained equation to the fourth.

(NB: It actually has $f_x(x,y)+o(1)$ on the right hand side, but I'm taking this as a typo unless I'm being an idiot.)

Why is this true? The worst part is that yesterday I had my head around it, but I seem to have forgotten again  today.

Let me know if more context would help.

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I thought more context might help, but the only step in the proof causing me issue is that which I have asked above which seems to me to be independent of the rest of the notes and indeed the rest of the proof, But if it helps the notes are here: http://dec41.user.srcf.net/h/IA_M/differential_equations/3_2

Comment: I don't understand the leap between the 3rd and 4th lines in the derivation at the top of the page.

Comment: I've edited the Question to include the entire proof (chain rule for two variables) you are asking about.  Please review to make sure I haven't introduced new typos.

Comment: Thanks a lot, apologies that it was initially unclear

Comment: It makes it much easier for Readers to agree with your surmise about the typo.  Seeing the notes makes it clear that the proof offered is really just a sketch, and indeed nothing is being said about the hypotheses required.  I think the general idea expressed by @AsherYartsev in the quickly posted response is that the partial (with respect to $y$) is continuous as a function of $x$, and this accounts for the introduction of the $o(1)$ "fudge factor" term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing my answer according to the new material given:

line2 -> line3: it uses Lagrange theorem ( F in respect to y is continuous in [y,y+δy] and differentiable in this segment, there for exists y1 belongs to [y,y+δy] that upholds:

Fy(x+δx,y1)δy = F(x+δx,y+δy)−F(x+δx,y)

in respect to Fy being continuous- we can assume:
Fy(x+δx,y1)δy = Fy(x+δx,y)δy + O(1)

line(3) -> line(4) :

here at the first argument we relate to F in respect to y , therefor,again, it continuous in area [x,x+δx]X[y,y+δy] thats the justification for:

Fy(x+δx,y) = Fy(x+δx,y) +O(1)

hope it was understandable!

Comment: also it seems the actual typo is fx(x+dx,y) on the left instead fy(x+dx,y)

Comment: The Question is now in better shape, so perhaps your Answer would bear polishing (editing) at this point.